# Calling a JS function if Razor handler is found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

At the moment I have a click function to show some item details when it is clicked on.

```
https://localhost:5001/MyPage?ID=3

    $(".show-detail").click(function (){
        var item-id = $(this).data('item-id');
        $("#red-section").hide();
        $(".red-panel").hide();
        $("#blue-" + item-id).show();
    });
```

The problem is that if I refresh the page it hides the section again. Can I get JS to look for a handler on page load and if it is present run the above function to hide some sections and show the one of interest?

```
https://localhost:5001/MyPage?ID=3&ItemID=4
```

If ItemID is present show #blue-4.

Comment: Pass the ID via model to your view and populate a hidden element with the value, if the value isn't empty pass it to the method

Comment: `var item-id = $(this).data('item-id');` does this really work? I mean `-` isn't allowed in variable names afaik.

Comment: Oh sorry, I renamed it so it made more sense in an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js approach. Also `@Ryan Wilson` gave you an idea with razor in comments

```
(function(){
    let currentUrl = window.location.href;
    let itemId = currentUrl.split('ItemID=')[1]
    if(!!itemId){
        var item-id = $(this).data(itemId);
        $("#red-section").hide();
        $(".red-panel").hide();
        $("#blue-" + item-id).show();
    }
})();
```